# Expected an identifier and instead found else javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, identifier

```
function compare(choice1,choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return "The result is a tie!"
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock")
    {
        if (choice2 === "scissors")
        return "Rock wins"
    }
    else
    {
        return "Paper wins"
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper")
    {
        if (choice2 === "rock")
        {
        return "Paper wins"
        }
        else
        {
            return "Scissors wins"
        }
    }
}
```

The error is the second else if statement. I am new to programming so I have no idea what is wrong. The error states that it expected an identifier and not else

Answer (score 0):

`if` ... `else if` ... `else` blocks will end with `else` block.

That is you can end it with only `else` block. Or to say, `else if` cannot come after `else`

Do this:

```
function compare(choice1,choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return "The result is a tie!"
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock")
    {
        if (choice2 === "scissors")
        return "Rock wins"
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper")
    {
        if (choice2 === "rock")
        {
        return "Paper wins"
        }
        else
        {
            return "Scissors wins"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Paper wins"
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *return* from an *if* block that only has one *else*, then there is no need for the else part.

```
function compare(choice1,choice2)
{
    if (choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return "The result is a tie!"
    }

    if (choice1 === "rock")
    {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") 
        {
        return "Rock wins"
        }
        return "Paper wins"
    }

    if (choice1 === "paper")
    {
        if (choice2 === "rock")
        {
        return "Paper wins"
        }
        return "Scissors wins"
    }
}
```

Which can be reduced further if the conditional `?:` operator is used:

```
function compare(choice1,choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!"
    }

    if (choice1 === "rock") {
        return choice2 === "scissors"? "Rock wins" : "Paper wins";
    }

    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        return choice2 === "rock"? "Paper wins" : "Scissors wins";
    }

    // You forgot this one
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        return choice2 === "rock"? "Rock wins" : "Scissors wins";
    }
}
```

Which is more compact and easier to read when there are many binary choices.